# Change web application's content database

Tags: 2010, 2013, web-application, configuration, content-database

Is it possible to configure my existing SharePoint 2010/2013 web application to point to a new/existing content database residing on another database server? If yes then how could I do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, but be sure to try this in your test environment first. Follow the steps in the article [SharePoint with more than one SQL instance: possible or not possible](http://www.sharepointboco.com/sharepoint-on-more-than-one-sql-instance-possible-or-not-possible-3/)

> ## On the SQL server
>
> 1. Backup the content database.
> 2. Restore the database on the second instance
> 3. Add the same permissions for the content database that you had on the source instance.
>
> ## On the SharePoint Server
>
> 4. Detach the content database from the web application :
>
> `stsadm.exe -o deletecontentdb  -url <URL name>  -databasename <database name>`
>
> 5. Attach the content database from the new instance to your web application  :
>
> `stsadm.exe -o addcontentdb -url <URL name>  -databasename <database name>  -databaseserver <database server name>`